# Best way to hold interior wall insulation in place prior to drywalling

Tags: drywall, insulation, sound-proofing

I'm insulating the interior walls in my house with rock wool insulation for sound proofing.  I'm having drywallers come in to drywall everything in one fell swoop and the insulation needs to be in place before they do anything.  I'm wondering the best way to hold the insulation in place prior to drywalling.  My initial thought is tape, but wonder if anyone has a better suggestion.

Comment: Masking or duct tape was my first reaction on reading the title, but iLikeDirt could be on to something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The insulation batts should stay in place by themselves via friction. If they're falling out, you're not cutting them snugly enough.

Comment: Even rock wool? It's pretty heavy.

Comment: Heavy? Are we using the same product? I'm taking about Roxul-type mineral wool batts. They stay within vertical stud cavities via friction very easily. If not, then you cut them too small. You're supposed to cut them such that they stay within the cavities via friction alone.

Comment: My experience with roxul type batts is that they want to stick out from the plane of the wall more than fiberglass. If this is the issue, don't worry about it -- the drywall will push it back in.